# [PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.2

Please help setting up model class cause I am getting an error:

> [PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.IncidentType_Diagnosis]

Error showing up when I am trying persist model class: MedicalIncident.java
which contain model class IncidentType_Diagnosis

```
package models;

@Entity
public class MedicalIncident {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@Required
public Customer customer;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@Required
public Place place;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@Required
public IncidentType incidentType;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public IncidentType_Diagnosis incidentType_Diagnosis;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public IncidentType_Infection incidentType_Infection;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Required
public IncidentType_MedicineApplication incidentType_MedicineApplication;



/**
 * Insert this new incident submission.
 */
public void toDataBase() {
    // persist object - add to entity manager
    JPA.em().persist(this);
}
}
```

And next model class of IncidentType_Diagnosis:

```
package models;
@Entity 

public class IncidentType_Diagnosis {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long id;
    public String name;

}
```

My controller:

```
    public class MedicalIncidents extends Controller {
       /**
       * Handle the form submission.
       */
       @Transactional
       public static Result submit() {
            if(filled_form.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(form.render(filled_form, display));
            } else {
                    filled_form.get().toDataBase(); // calling in model method
                    return redirect(routes.Index.index());
            }
       }
    }
```

Also one of my models classes which in relation with medicalincident model class

```
package models;
@Entity 
public class IncidentType_Diagnosis {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    public static List<IncidentType_Diagnosis> getList()   {
        List<IncidentType_Diagnosis> allIncidentType_Diagnosiss = (List<IncidentType_Diagnosis>) JPA.em()
                .createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM IncidentType_Diagnosis", IncidentType_Diagnosis.class)
                .getResultList();
        return allIncidentType_Diagnosiss;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you are actually saving the objects

Comment: It is in `package models -> @Entity public class MedicalIncident -> public void toDataBase()`

Answer (score 0):

Usually `detached` model means that it is not in `transaction scope` where you wanted to persist your object. In other words, your `transaction` is hanged in the air. So you need to make it transactional by using `@Transactional`

EDITED:

No, models should be only for tables. DAO methods should be in transaction, also if you write something like this, please write tests for it in transaction scope.

Comment: `@Transactional` adnotation is set in `controlles -> MedicalIncidents -> submit()` I've upload code above. Should it be set in models too?